# Eye Gaze Estimation using Mediapipe?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mediapipe

I am looking to estimate a gaze angle of a detected face using Mediapipe. I currently have a working solution that solves for head rotation, and I am trying to offset that rotation by a euler angle that corresponds to the face's estimated gaze. I have found ways to do this using OpenFace and Dlib, but not MediaPipe and not in C# (writing this in Unity). Does anyone have any starting points?